# Can i ask about a particular system location in android(I mean about its contents)

Tags: discussion

I want to know about the info stored in a file in a particular location. Can I ask about it here?

Comment: Would you mind providing an example for the file location? If it's related to an issue using Android, then no wonder you're good to ask it here.  If it's just any file you would want to know about irrespective of any issue associated with it, then I would wait for others to chime in here to tell, whether you should ask or not. :)

Comment: sorry but i have asked the question already @Firelord

Comment: This is too vague to be useful. How about posting the question you want to ask?

Comment: here is the question http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/114341/what-does-the-file-data-misc-wifi-softap-conf-contain @AlE.

Comment: Well then I guess you have the answer to your question here. It seems on-topic to me (and others) and you seem to have gotten a good answer. This question here is still too vague to be useful to future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discussing with two to three people and posting this type of question, I found that

> No one has any objection on these type of question.

Since it is not possible for all to know about the file standard of android these type of questions will be helpful for people like me.

I wanted to know where the saved wifi-passwords are stored and I got an answer from this SE site and therefore I wanted to know about the other files stores in same directory as that of the file which contained the saved wifi passwords.

So this type of questions can be helpful this way.

Best Regards,

Jasser